# Distance of two points in a rotated rectangle

Tags: geometry

I have a rectangle which I need to rotate (blue rectangle in the image). The rotation origin is a random point somewhere inside of this rectangle (point Z in the image). The rotation is ALWAYS clockwise. Actually, the angle is set as well but that's not really important.

After the rotation I need to find out the **distance between the points A and Z** on the *x axis* and **D and Z** - on the *y axis*. So basically I need to find the coordinates of point Z inside the "wrapping" (imaginary) rectangle that would exactly contain the blue rectangle and would not be rotated.

I was trying to translate the rotation center to 0, 0 but I am honestly confused with the swapped axis and the clockwise rotation. How should I go about it?

Any help appreciated! Thanks a lot.[image]

Comment: Which dimensions do you know before the rotation?

Comment: As you are only interested in the location of the point relative to the bounding box, it does not matter where you put the centre of rotation (using a different centre gives the same end result apart from a translation, but the bounding box gets translated too so it does not matter). I would put the centre of rotation at D, find the rotated coordinates of A and Z, and then you are virtually done.

Comment: @MattiP. I know every rectangle side (so A, D coords as well), Z's coords, rotation angle.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Oh, so right! Thanks, I will try this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Since we are interested only in the distances related to the rotation center, nothing changes if we move the rotation center to the origin and consider all the coordinates with respect to that point. So consider a "straight" (meaning, parallel to the $y$-axis) line $AD$, so that $A=(x_0, a_0)$ and $D=(x_0, d_0)$. We rotate this line about the origin and call the new line $A'D'$ with coordinates $A'=(a_x, a_y)$ and $D'=(d_x,d_y)$.

Notice that both points $A$ and $D$ travel the angle $\theta$ about the origin. Therefore, it is easy to compute the new coordinates of each point. The standard rotation matrix is
$$
R_{\text{counter-cw}} =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & -\sin{\theta} \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array}
\right]
$$
but this is defined for counterclockwise rotations. Therefore, we have to just flip the sign of the angle (or take the transpose - these are the same in this case), giving
$$
R_{\text{cw}} =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & \sin{\theta} \\
-\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Now, the new coordinates are obtained by matrix multiplication:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_x \\ a_y
\end{array}
\right)
= R_{\text{cw}} 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_0 \\ a_0
\end{array}
\right)
= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x_0 \cos \theta +  a_0\sin \theta \\
- x_0\sin \theta +  a_0\cos \theta
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
d_x \\ d_y
\end{array}
\right)
= R_{\text{cw}} 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_0 \\ d_0
\end{array}
\right)
= 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x_0 \cos \theta +  d_0\sin \theta \\
- x_0\sin \theta +  d_0\cos \theta
\end{array}
\right)
$$
You wanted the distance in the $x$-direction, so it's easy to just take the absolute values of the $x$-coordinates of these results.